# Adding installation parameters to a contentful App

Tags: contentful, contentful-management, contentful-api, contentful-vault

Struggling to find a working example or a document that explains how to set contentful app installation params. I can see how to get them from the SDK but settings them i cant.

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your app has a [Config Location](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/extensibility/app-framework/locations/#app-configuration) which means you are building UI that will be shown to the user during and after installation of your app. In this location, there is an SDK method called `sdk.app.onConfigure`. This method takes a function which will return an object which is called `targetState`.

`targetState` documentation can be found [here](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/extensibility/app-framework/target-state/).

Let's take a React Config app as an example where we will set `{foo: 'bar'}` as our installation parameters:

```js
export default class Config extends Component<ConfigProps, ConfigState> {
  constructor(props: ConfigProps) {
    super(props);
    // letting the SDK know we have a configuration function which will
    // return `targetState`
    props.sdk.app.onConfigure(() => this.onConfigure());
  }

  // This method will be called when a user clicks on "Install"
  // or "Save" on the configuration screen.
  onConfigure = async () => {
    // the object returned here is what Contentful calls `targetState`.
    // it is simply a configuration object set when the app is installed or updated
    return {
        parameters: { installation: { foo: 'bar' } }
    };
  };
```

In the example above, when a user hits "Install" or "Save" on the app's Config location, the installation parameter object of `{foo: 'bar'}` will be saved and can then be accessed in other app locations via the SDK.

On the off chance you are purely using the API to create or modify an `AppInstallation`, you can use the Content Management API to update the app's `parameters` as described in the documentation [here](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/app-installations).

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but i also struggled with it. I found a tutorial here:
https://dev.to/wiommi/how-i-built-a-contentful-app-combined-with-commerce-js-iii-33fo

They are added manually in ConfigScreen.tsx

You need to add them to your interface

```
export interface AppInstallationParameters {}
```

fx:

```
export interface AppInstallationParameters {
  apiKey?: string;
  projectId?: string;
}
```

And then set them manually with fx.

```
setParameters({ ...parameters, [PARAMETERNAME]: [PARAMETERVALUE] });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also setup installation parameters at installation time, however, you need to install using this endpoint and provide the parameters:

```
PUT /spaces/{space_id}/environments/{environment_id}/app_installations/{app_definition_id}
```

```
{
  "parameters": {
    "hello": "world"
  }
}
```

See https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/app-installations/app-installation/install-or-update-an-app/console/curl